# How can I execute python file?

Tags: python

I made `test.py` and ran `chmod u+x test.py`. It works if I run `python test.py` but not `./test.py`. What am I doing wrong?

```
./test.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"HelloWorld"'
./test.py: line 1: `print ("HelloWorld")'
```

Comment: Try adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your Python file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt) for more info.

Comment: please show your source code for your script as well